# Reversing a shift, and xored algorithm

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to write a program which will reverse `msg ^ ((msg << shift) & key)`, and give me the original message back, and that too for arbitrarily large messages. Also the key length in binary must be greater than the shift. These are the assumptions I have restricted myself to. Also the message is at least or greater than the key. (The code block does have a check for when the key length is shorter than the shift but that case isn't really very interesting and I have just included for the sake of completeness of the program.)

I have tried doing the decoding when the key is `0xffffffff`, and it is right shifted, instead of left.

```py
def decode(value,shift):
    binary = format(value,'b')
    valueLen = len(binary) - shift
    y = value
    if valueLen < 0:
        return value
    else:
        for i in range(valueLen):
            y = value ^ y << shift
        y = y >> (shift*valueLen) 
        return y
```

It reveres the xor cipher by shifting the bits `shift` times and then xoring to get the next stage, making use of the fact `(a ^ b) ^ (b ^ c) = a ^ c`, until we get the entire message, and then strips the redundant bits.

However with the addition with a key, I am completely clueless. I would be glad if anyone would give me pointers to approach it programmatically.

For anyone interested, here is the entire encryption algorithm.

```py
msg = msg ^ (msg >> 6)
msg = msg ^ ((msg << 13) & 275128763)
msg = msg ^ ((msg << 20) & 2186268085)
msg = msg ^ (msg >> 14)
```

Comment: You should add parentheses as necessary to `msg ^ msg << shift & key` to make the order of operations clear. It's ambiguous as it stands now. You should also show the entire encryption algorithm, because reversal of just this single piece is not possible in general.

Comment: Yeah, it was my fault. I will do the proper edits.

Comment: Who says that this is reversible? Try find a shift and a message where it is not. Not all operations are reversible, either due to information loss or because they are designed that way (one way hashes, for instance).

Comment: At least for 32 bit integers, with a key less than 32 bits, and a shift less than the key length, I have not yet found a counter example where it is not reversible.